How to add the css into custom develop liquid shopify theme from the scratch for the resposive?
I develop the shopify theme from the scratch and now I don't know where should i add the media query for the responsive for the sections and the template.
When i add multiple media query it pick only the one and ignore the others.
Please anyone guide me for this problem?
Image show which page and section I want to add the media query to make responsive

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Thank you for your reply.
I found the problem and the problem was I did not add the viewport meta in the header which cause this issue.
